# Despite set.seed - I get different results than others in R

Tags: r, random-seed

When doing

```
set.seed(123)
smaple(1:100,3)
```

in R, I get `29 79 41` which is not what others are getting.
Why is this? And how can I change it?

When typing `sessionInfo()` I get a line which says

```
Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding
```

Is that perhaps a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the default values in `RNGkind`

-default settings in `R 4.1.0` - MacOS (which could vary based on R version - see below)

```
RNGkind()
#[1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"        "Rejection"
```

-testing

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1:100, 3)
#[1] 31 79 51
```

-Change the values in `RNGkind` to match with the OP's

```
RNGkind(kind = "Mersenne-Twister",
        normal.kind = "Inversion", 
        sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

-test again

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1:100, 3)
[1] 29 79 41
```

---

According to `?RNGkind`

> sample.kind can be "Rounding" or "Rejection", or partial matches to these. The former was the default in versions prior to 3.6.0: it made sample noticeably non-uniform on large populations, and should only be used for reproduction of old results. See PR#17494 for a discussion.